# Shell script/command to rename files to their crc32 values?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

How would I use unix shell to rename files in a directory, so that their names are their crc32 hash + their original extension?

Example:

`1-s2.0-105687199400063A-main.pdf` => `e3492cf3.pdf`

Comment: How do you get `pdf` in your example?

Comment: @fedorqui: sry, fixed

Comment: Did you consider [Compress::Zlib::crc32](http://perldoc.perl.org/Compress/Zlib.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for file in `ls`; do mv "${file}" `cksum "${file}" | cut -d' ' -f1`."${file##*.}"; done
```

Maybe `awk` is the better way to do this than `cut`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work:

```
for file in /your/dir/*
do
  extension="${file##*.}"   #gets the block after the last dot, that is, the extension
  new_name=$(crc32 $file)   #calculates the crc32 value of the file
  mv $file ${new_name}.${extension} #renames by moving the original file to the new name
done
```